# Repo will not clone, "Permission Denied", using git module

Tags: ansible

I've looked at similar questions, but not found an answer yet.

I can SSH in to the server (Ubuntu 16.04) and clone my git repo manually. This leaves me to believe it isn't an SSHForwardAgent issue.

The error is pretty typical:

```
"Cloning into bare repository '/home/deploy/apps/MYPROJECT/production/cached-copy'...", 
"Permission denied (publickey).", 
"fatal: Could not read from remote repository.",
```

ansible.cnf:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

The role looks like this:

```
- name: Update the bare Git repository
  become_user: "{{ deploy_user }}"
  git:
    repo: "git@github.com:MYUSER/MYPROJECT.git"
    dest: "{{ deploy_to }}/cached-copy"
    version: "{{ branch }}"
    bare: yes
    update: yes
    accept_hostkey: yes
    ssh_opts: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ForwardAgent=yes"
```

The verbose output from Ansible is:

```
"changed": false, 
"cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --bare '' /home/deploy/apps/MYPROJECT/production/cached-copy", 
"failed": true, 
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"accept_hostkey": true, 
"bare": true, 
"clone": true, 
"depth": null, 
"dest": "/home/deploy/apps/MYPROJECT/production/cached-copy", 
"executable": null, 
"force": false, 
"key_file": null, 
"recursive": true, 
"reference": null, 
"refspec": null, 
"remote": "origin", 
"repo": "git@github.com:MYUSER/MYPROJECT.git", 
"ssh_opts": "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ForwardAgent=yes", 
"track_submodules": false, 
"umask": null, 
"update": true, 
"verify_commit": false, 
"version": "master"
```

Use of MYUSER and MYPROJECT is to retract such information.

One thing that looks suspect is `cmd` it does not contain the repo URL, is this normal?

If I change `-o ForwardAgent=yes` to `-A` I get a different error: `Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt`.

Also I know AgentForward is working because if I ssh in to the server and do `ssh -T git@github.com` I get the expected "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.".

Please note I do not want to install a private key on the server.

*Update*: Here is a gist of the verbose output: https://gist.github.com/krisleech/8bfbf817c237258a672b3b3393fea8dd

On the other hand this seems to work fine:

```
- name: "Test github"
  command: ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: What is `become_user: "{{ deploy_user }}"` for? Is it different from your remote user (you make ssh connection with)? In this case your ssh agent socket may be inaccessible after _becoming_ different user.

Comment: I have `admin` and `deploy` users, the admin user can sudo, the `deploy` user can not. I tried removing this line, but no effect. I can ssh in as either user and clone the repo.

Comment: Do you call tasks with `become` option (post `-vvv` output of ssh command executed for this task)? Ssh agent works when you login as either user, but stops working when you `sudo` after logging in.

Comment: I think you might have the right answer here, if I remove `become_user` it does seem to work. But I have no idea why the resulting cloned files belong to `deploy` user without having `become_user`, shouldn't they be owned by `root`.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorovI I just added a gist to the verbose output at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your verbose output I see that:

- first, you ssh to remote box with `admin` user and `ForwardAgent=yes`
- then, you sudo as `deploy` to run Ansible task (git module)

This is the scenario I described in comments, when doing sudo (with usual settings) you effectively disable ssh agent access.

To make this work, you either need to ssh with `deploy` user directly (and not with `admin->deploy`), or setup `sudo` on your destination box to allow keeping environment variables, see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/118932/336047) for details.

> Add `Defaults    env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to sudoers

Answer (score 0):

The protocol for the `repo` parameter is missing. From `ansible-doc`:

> ```
> # Example git checkout from Ansible Playbooks
>   - git:
>      repo: git://foosball.example.org/path/to/repo.git
>      dest: /srv/checkout
> ```

Try adding `git:` or `ssh:` to the `repo` parameter.

Comment: I tried both `ssh://` and and `https://`, unfortunately the same error. And `git://` isn't an option with github. But good catch anyway.

Comment: By the way if I do ` git clone git://git@github.com:krisleech/mos.git` on the server I get `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`.